# Локальный import css в React

Tags: css, reactjs

Как подключить стили css из файла .css только для одной компоненты(т.е. ЛОКАЛЬНО)?

Ситуация такая что мне нужно прикрутить сторонний лэндинг к нашему приложению на react. Но у нас очень много зависимостей от других либ.
И в лендинге используется bootstrap и др. Дак вот если я делаю import стилей для лэндинга, вся админка падает, потому что стили переопределяются.
css module не вариант, потому что в css 15к строк и много стилей применимо к тэгам html, body и др.

p.s. обычный import css подключает собирает все стили react в один ещё до подключения компоненты.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось всё банальным  `...ваш css...`  внутри рендера компоненты!
Обратите внимание что кавычки косые. Я вообще все стили вынес в css.js
а внутри css.js:
export const style = `html {...}`
Но если у вас будут относительные пути внутри css, тогда их придётся тоже ипортировать в css.js.